# CSS vertical-align doesnt work with dimension expressed as percentage

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I have two nested containers, .button-1x1 and the inner .button-content. I want to express .button-content dimension as a percentage, and if i do the vertical-align property is not running. It runs fine if i do set width and height as px values. Why?

The outer container has its dimension expressed as px values, so i thought i could express the nested dimension as a percentage, this would keep my css more maintenable. But this doesnt work.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pjZ8g/5/

Code:

```
<style type='text/css'>
.absolute {position:absolute}
.bg-teal {
  background-color:#abc;
}
.button-content {
  width:100%; /** Change this to px, and it will work */
  height:100%; /** Change this to px, and it will work */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.button-1x1 {
  width:230px;
  height:230px;
}
</style>
<div class='button-1x1 relative'>
    <div class='button button-1x1 bg-teal absolute'>
      <div class='button-content'>
        <span>test1</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach to techfoobar's.

Change the `<div class='button button-1x1 bg-teal absolute'>` styling to include `display:table`.

See http://jsfiddle.net/pjZ8g/9/

Answer (score 1):

Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25JXw/1/

You can achieve this by specifying a `line-height` for the DIV inside which you want to middle-align the content. To do this while keeping the inner DIV's CSS generic you can inherit the `line-height` form the parent as you can see in the demo.

**CSS**

```
.button-content {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display: block; /* change to block OR remove */
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  line-height: inherit; /* new */
}

.button-1x1 {
  width:230px;
  height:230px;
  line-height: 230px; /* new */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite a fine solution but there's still a problem: my layout gets broken if text spans on more lines, try with a random line break and you'll see

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. Try Alohci's solutions. It seems to work correctly in all cases and is more correct theoretically too since table-cells are supposed to be inside tables.